# When I'm in the MS-DOS command line, what "language" am I using?

Tags: batch-file, dos

And, are the common commands like `cd..` of the same language as batch processes that can be programmed in MS-DOS? cheers.

Comment: Are you actually using dos? Or are you using the windows command prompt (which looks very like dos)? Because dude if your still using dos then, like . . . WOW!

Comment: @Binary, FreeDOS is still going strong.

Comment: Dude DOS is still on the go? Even more WOW! (which is slighty ironic considering that WOW now also stands for Works On Windows)

Comment: What? Since when is WOW not World of Warcraft? :/

Answer (score 5):

That would be the command language or batch language, also called `cmd.exe` unless you're *really* on MS-DOS.

And the same commands you use at the command line are available to those batch files you discuss even though there's slight differences such as the use of `%%` for `for` variables inside the batch files.

It's come a *long* way since the bad old days of MS-DOS batch programming but it still doesn't come close to the ease of use of `bash` or `ksh` under UNIX. I suspect most modern batch programs under Windows will now be using PowerShell.

Comment: +1 for mention of powershell, it's a shame it took so long for a proper windows shell to be developed

Answer (score 0):

Batch language.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Prompt

Answer (score 0):

Practically everything that works in a batchfile will also work on the command prompt, as both are more or less the same
(Batchfiles beeing simply a bunch of prewritten sequencial commands)

Some things used in batchfiles won't do you any good on the command prompt, i.e. call [batchfile],goto and goto-labels, variables, etc.